# trying to access string resources inside fragment.. always notFoundException

Tags: android, android-fragments

I want to access string resources from fragment this what I did:

```
public class MainFragment extends Fragment {

  ...

  public MainFragment() {
    // Required empty public constructor
  }

  public static MainFragment fragment(){
    MainFragment fragment = new MainFragment();
    return fragment;
  }

  @Override
  public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    ...

    kickInfo.setText(R.string.kickInfoPertama);
```

I always get notFoundexception error:

> android.content.res.Resources$NotFoundException: String resource ID #0x7f09003e

I also have try use:

```
kickInfo.setText(getActitvity().getString(R.string.KickInfoPertama));
```

also

```
kickInfo.setText(getActitvity().getResources().getString(R.string.KickInfoPertama));
```

but always get the same result. What have I missed?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You should not use uppercase letters in a string value :

change KickInfoPertama to kickinfopertama and :

Try this :

kickInfo.setText(getString(R.string.kickinfopertama));

Answer (score 0):

Please follow the `xml` convention for defining `string` in `strings.xml`

```
<string name="kick_info_pertama">Kick info pertama</string>
```

Please detect if your string really existed in `strings.xml` and use this code in your `Fragment`

```
getActivity().getString(R.string.your_resource_id);
```